# Rails: Can't load two Jquery scripts in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, algolia

i have a problem with my rails app - I have two scripts that keeping each others from works. On the first hand, the algolia search engine script (which is working well)

in app/assets/javascript/algolia.js:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Replace the following values by your ApplicationID and ApiKey.
    var algolia = new AlgoliaSearch('MYAPPID', 'MYAPPPWD');
    // replace YourIndexName by the name of the index you want to query.
    var index = algolia.initIndex('Pin');

    // Mustache templating by Hogan.js (http://mustache.github.io/)
    var template = Hogan.compile('<div class="hit">' +
      '<a href="http://0.0.0.0:3000/pins/{{{slug}}}">'
     +
      '<div class="name">' +
        '{{{ _highlightResult.description.value }}} ' +
      '</div>' +
      '</a>' +
      '</div>');


    // typeahead.js initialization
    $('#user-search').typeahead(null, {
      source: index.ttAdapter({ hitsPerPage: 5 }),

      displayKey: 'description',
      templates: {
        suggestion: function(hit) {

          // select matching attributes only
          hit.matchingAttributes = [];
          for (var attribute in hit._highlightResult) {
            if (attribute === 'name' || attribute == 'company') {
              // already handled by the template
              continue;
            }
            // all others attributes that are matching should be added in the matchingAttributes array
            // so we can display them in the dropdown menu. Non-matching attributes are skipped.
            if (hit._highlightResult[attribute].matchLevel !== 'none') {
              hit.matchingAttributes.push({ attribute: attribute, value: hit._highlightResult[attribute].value });
            }
          }

          // render the hit using Hogan.js
          return template.render(hit);

        }
      }
    });
  });
```

And a script to load a popup using [magnific-popup-gem](https://github.com/joshuajansen/magnific-popup-rails)

```
 $(function() {
          $('.please-login').magnificPopup({
          type: 'inline',
          preloader: false,
          focus: '#username',
          modal: true
          });
          $(document).on('click', '.please-login-dismiss', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.magnificPopup.close();
          });
          });
```

it looks line those lines are making the magnific popup doesn't works.

```
 <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Typahead.js is used to display the auto-completion menu -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.4/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Hogan.js is used to render the hits using Mustache.js templating -->
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/hogan.js/3.0.0/hogan.common.js"></script>
    <!-- Algolia -->
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/latest/algoliasearch.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas how I could fix this please?

Comment: Have you already tried putting the magnific popup "ready" handler code inside the algolia.js ready handler function to the bottom (and the top) and removing the second $(function....) handler to eliminate any potential indirect dependencies between algolia and magnific popup? If so, what were the results in the bottom and top cases as you shouldn't rely on ready handler evaluation ordering when using multiple readys in jQuery. This information would help eliminate a set of root causes.

Also are the results +always+ resulting in same broken magnific popup behavior every time or not?

Comment: Thanks Susan, @Shipow answers fixed the problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that jquery is loaded only once before every script which depend of it.

Jquery should have already been loaded by rails so you probably don't need this line

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, removing this line fixed the problem - The doublon caused the error. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your second file is well loaded:

Verify if these lines are present:
in application.css:
    *= require magnific-popup

in application.js:
    //= require magnific-popup

Use a web console as firebug for firefox or the base one on chrome and look for in 
Sources -> localhost -> assets  and see if you find your files.

If you don't find it: It is a link problem (little mistake as spelling or something basic)
If you find it: It is a problem in your script (watch css class are present, use the debugger in the web console)